# Read the first index of array for checking a boolean

Tags: arrays, swift

This is a very basic question, but sorry I couldn't find its answer
In the first index of an array I have a `boolean` and I want to check it that it's true or not

I can simply do that

```
if myarray[0].isRunning == true {
}
```

But this is bad, but as I think, I can do it with first index, something like it:

```
if myarray.firstIndex (where: {$0.isRunning == "true}) {
}
```

But I got an error on this, I think it's not quite right, could anyone teach me how I can use firstIndex to check a boolean?

Thanks

Comment: Removing the quotation mark in `"true` should help ... Otherwise: Show how `myarray` is defined, and the exact error message. Also take care to copy/paste your code correctly, it surely is not `If` with an uppercase `I`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array could be empty this is a safe way

```
if myarray.first?.isRunning == true {
```

or (also safe)

```
if !myarray.isEmpty, myarray[0].isRunning {
```

If the array is never empty then your *bad* way is good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this:

```
if myarray.first?.isRunning {
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to check whether the first item in the array has an attribute of `isRunning == true` use:

```
if myarray.first?.isRunning == true {

}
```

If you would like to get the first item in the array where `isRunning` does equal true:

```
if let i = myarray.firstIndex(where: { $0.isRunning == true }) {
    let obj = myarray[i]
    print("\(obj) is the first object where running is true.")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried :

```
If myarray[0].isRunning.elementsEqual("true")
{

}
```